# CakePHP 2 assumption concerning AfterSave

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.5

As I have not found a reply to this question even though I have Googled for an answer, I have to ask it here.

**Can I assume that I always have ID (PK column) in *$this->data[$this->alias]*['id'] inside afterSave method?**

If I cannot assume this, in what situation afterSave would not give PK?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It will exist only for single auto-increment primary keys named "id". Compound keys or none auto-increment keys might not be set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `afterSave()` you want to be using `$this->id` which is always set as `afterSave` is only called if the save is successful, i.e. a row was either inserted or updated in the database.

If you [look at the code](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.x/lib/Cake/Model/Model.php#L1956-L1970) for `save()` in `Model.php` you'll see that if the save isn't successful the method returns before the `afterSave` callback is initiated.

Comment: Did Cake 2 not support compound keys?

Comment: "In afterSave() you want to be using $this->id which is always set as afterSave is only called if the save is successful, i.e. a row was either inserted or updated in the database." This is what I wanted to confirm, that $this->id is always set on successful save. I thank thee.